# Laravel enable VerifyCsrfToken for specific routes

Tags: laravel

Running Laravel 5.3 I have certain API routes that my application calls for guests on the site. 
I do not want these to be completely public and directly accessible so I'm think that I need to add "VerifyCsrfToken" middleware to these routes only.

I believe that would at least confirm that the request is coming from my application.

Any guidance on this? Thanks

**UPDATE:**
After adding the csrf middleware to the route as suggested by @motie and then also adding the "StartSession" middleware the route seemed to work - but it did not actually work according to what I had hoped - Was hoping for it to compare tokens and the fail if mismatch - but that was not the case.

The VerifyCsrfToken has the following in its checks:

```
if (
        $this->isReading($request) ||
        $this->runningUnitTests() ||
        $this->shouldPassThrough($request) ||
        $this->tokensMatch($request)
    )
```

It requires any one of those conditions to pass - which is a bit strange as the "isReading" simply checks if the request uses "GET" method present so it always passes...

- Also calling the `StartSession` middleware seems to refresh the csrf token for the API route which means the web token and api call token are not the same. I'm think it might just be easier to add this route to the "Web" routes or add the "web" middleware to it...

Comment: If you want to enable CSRF checking for API route then you can simply add the route in *web.php* instead of *api.php*...

Answer (score 1):

To enable csrf for some api routes, define an alias for it in  ```app/Http/Kernel.php::

```
tected $routeMiddleware = [
   ...
    'csrf' => \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    'session' => \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
   ...
]
```

then you will be able to add it to the routes you want in api.php.

`Route::get('secured-api-route', ['middleware' => 'csrf'])`;

## Edit:

Using the csrf middleware requires activating the session middleware. Hence, it will be better to create a new middleware group than registering separate middlewares.

```
    'api.csrf' => [
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    ]
```

Comment: close... but it gives me a "Session store not set on request." I presume cause I need to include the StartSession middleware as well.

Comment: yes..clearly, it does, I was too much optimitic to give in simple answer :p

Comment: So the issue now is that the token generated by the API middleware is not the same as the web token causing a mismatch. Even tried use the "web" middleware but still it seems to be different.

Comment: You should send the csrf token with your requests, in the http headers named 'X-CSRF-TOKEN' or as a form input named "_token".


Note: csrf does not protect reading methods, namely GET, HEAD and OPTIONS

Comment: it is being sent through - just not matching